# Can questions about Acquia Dev Desktop be asked here?

Tags: support, questions

I'm not sure; therefore I first ask here: Are questions about Acquia Dev Desktop allowed in Drupal Answers? If not, could you please explain why?

Comment: Just make sure you avoid problems that might be more probable in this case. See [my answer to somehow similar question](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/a/3328/16495)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a tool used exclusively from people who develop sites using Drupal, yes, they can be asked on *Drupal Answers*. In fact, there are (at this moment) 34 questions tagged [acquia-dev-desktop](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acquia-dev-desktop).

It is not different from the case of questions about Drush. The difference is that probably there are more questions you can ask about Drush than Acquia Dev Desktop; in both the cases, you don't use them for making sites with WordPress.

Comment: I use drush for a year and half and only two days ago discovered the very existence of ADD2. I'll be happy to ask (and even answer) about it, in any suitable time! :)

Comment: @benos Maybe you haven't come across [Quickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/quickstart) in that case? Arguably even better than ADD

Comment: I am sad to see this project is no longer supported...

Comment: I didn't notice that, sorry. Shame